# How to pass character `^` to my program from commnd prompt?

Tags: c++, argv, argc

I have this simple example which is about a calculator:

- Enter the first operand then the operator, If the operator is a unary then there's no need to enter the second one. So print the result e.g: the square if a number doesn't need second operand.
- The input can be passed into the program from command prompt otherwise after program starts from input stream.
- The reason why I want to pass the input as arguments to the program is I want to invoke my program from a command prompt sometimes, so I can issue: `calc 57 + 12` + enter: I get 69.
- The program works fine but when it comes to the square operator which in my case I've used `^` it is ok from input stream (std::cin) But if I pass it through command prompt I cannot?!

  ```
  int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

      int a = 0;
      int b = 0;
      char op = '\0';

      if(argc < 2){
          std::cout << "a: ";
          std::cin >> a;
          std::cout << "op: ";
          std::cin >> op;

          switch(op){
              case '^':
                  std::cout <<  a << " ^2 " << " = " 
                      << a * a << std::endl;
              break;
              case '+':
                  std::cout << "b: ";
                  std::cin >> b;
                  std::cout <<   a << " + " << b << " = " 
                  << a + b << std::endl;
              break;
              case '-':
                  std::cout << "b: ";
                  std::cin >> b;
                  std::cout << a << " - " << b << " = " 
                  << a - b << std::endl;
              break;
              case '*':
                  std::cout << "b: ";
                  std::cin >> b;
                  std::cout << a << " * " << b << " = " 
                  <<  a * b << std::endl;
              break;
              case '/':
                  std::cout << "b: ";
                  std::cin >> b;
                  std::cout << a << " / " << b << " = " 
                  << a / b << std::endl;
              break;
              case '%':
                  std::cout << "b: ";
                  std::cin >> b;
                  std::cout << a << " % " << b << " = " 
                  <<  a % b << std::endl;
              break;
          }

      }
      else{
          a = atoi(argv[1]);
          op = argv[2][0];
      }

      if(argc == 3){
          std::cout << "argc = 3" << std::endl;
          std::cout << "op: " << op << std::endl;
          switch(op){
              case '^':
                  std::cout <<  a << " ^2 " << " = " 
                      << a * a << std::endl;
              break;
          }
      }
      else
          if(argc == 4){
              b = atoi(argv[3]);
              switch(op){
                  case '+':
                      std::cout <<   a << " + " << b << " = " 
                      << a + b << std::endl;
                  break;
                  case '-':
                      std::cout << a << " - " << b << " = " 
                      << a - b << std::endl;
                  break;
                  case '*':
                      std::cout << a << " * " << b << " = " 
                      <<  a * b << std::endl;
                  break;
                  case '/':
                      std::cout << a << " / " << b << " = " 
                      << a / b << std::endl;
                  break;
                  case '%':
                      std::cout << a << " % " << b << " = " 
                      <<  a % b << std::endl;
                  break;
              }
          }

      std::cin.get()
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- If I from command prompt issue: `calc 7 ^` I didn't get `49` but the command asks me `more ?`.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually not a C++ issue, it's a terminal issue. In cmd and windows batch `^` is the symbol for line continuations.

To actually pass a `^` you have to escape it. And the symbol for escaping is ... [[drum roll]] `^`. So you have to write `^^` in cmd to actually pass a `^` to your program.

Comment: But When I pass `^^`it didn't work for me e.g: `calc 5 ^^` when I press enter I get: `argc = 3
op: ^` and not `25`?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Works for me when I fix other problems in your code that prevent it from compiling. Show us your _actual_ [mcve], not some facsimile with an unknown quantity of alterations.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: This is all the code. What are the errors in the code? You'd rather state them.

Answer (score 4):

The ^ character is nothing special to c++. There's nothing wrong with processing it as any other character. Your problem stems from your shell. However, you're not telling us which shell you're using. As you're having trouble with ^ I am guessing you run your program in a Windows environment. In Windows command prompt the ^ is the escape character. You're escaping the next character (cmd prompt discards the ^ and treats the next character as just that: a character) so that's why you're not finding the ^ itself in your program's arguments.

Some more info on special shell characters can be found here:

- cmd prompt: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php
- bash: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/special-bash-parameters-in-script-linux.html